# Why is my content overlapping with my footer?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using itextsharp to generate pdf ...i m getting problem is my content/text coming upon footer...i want to automatically break down content to new page...if it comes upon footer..

right now i m using document.newpage()

but i want to do it automatically that my page /content automatically breakdown to new page..it should not come to header/footer of page...

FOr Information i create header/footer through this class

```
public class ITextEvents : PdfPageEventHelper
```

and i used this function

```
public override void OnEndPage
```

I m attaching also the result that i m getting right now...
please help me on this...i can share more information if you ask in comments

[image]

i want this last box to come automatically to new  page.....

Comment: Why is this tagged with HTML and CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are adding the flowing content using `document.add()`, you have to make sure that you define a bottom margin that is sufficiently large to accommodate the footer.

You don't share the code you have in your `OnEndPage` method, but suppose that you have something like:

```
canvas.MoveTo(36, 50);
canvas.LineTo(559, 50);
canvas.Strike();
```

This draws a line from `x = 36` to `x = 559` at `y = 50`.

Suppose you have created your `Document` like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
```

In this case, you are creating a document with pages in the A4 format (595 x 842 user units) and margins of 36 user units. As the bottom margin is only 36 user units, your content risks overlapping with the line drawn at 50 user units from the bottom.

You should change the line where you create the `Document` like this:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 36, 55);
```

Now you have a bottom margin of 55 user units and the line you draw at 50 user units no longer overlaps.

**Note:** I use the term *user units* because that's how we define measurements in PDF. By default 1 user unit equals 1 point. The default margin is 36 user units or half an inch.

Comment: your suggestion is good but in my pdf have an cover page which covers full width of pdf from left to right so if i apply margin in document it will automatically added to that cover page also...which i dont want to apply on cover page ....any other approach to do this....

Comment: Then (1) define left and right border as 0, or (2) define a different margin for the cover page. (Don't create an issue about something that isn't a problem.)