# Conflict of tables, when footer one is firmly set to the bottom

Tags: java, itext

The following screen shot demonstrates the problem I am experiencing:

NOTE: I want to have that green table only on the very end of the whole pdf file, not on every single page!

[image]

Is there some elegant solution to find the X,Y location on the page and manually create new page?

This is my code (using iText):

```
private static PdfPTable createHeaderTable() throws DocumentException {
    int[] columnWidths = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    PdfPTable datatable = new PdfPTable(columnWidths.length);
    datatable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    datatable.setWidths(columnWidths);
    datatable.getDefaultCell().setPadding(5);       

    datatable.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    datatable.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(alignment);

    for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
        addCellToTable(datatable, horizontalAlignmentLeft, 
        verticalAlignmentMiddle,"Přehledová tabulka", columnWidths.length,
         1, fontTypeBold, fontSizeRegular,cellLayout_Bottom);           
    }


    private static PdfPTable createFooterTable() throws DocumentException {
    int[] columnWidths = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    PdfPTable datatable = new PdfPTable(columnWidths.length);
    // datatable.setKeepTogether(true);
    datatable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    datatable.setWidths(columnWidths);
    datatable.getDefaultCell().setPadding(5);

    datatable.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    datatable.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(alignment);

    //.... added cells identically as by header table (higher here) ...

    return datatable;
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
        new FileOutputStream("C:/radek-folder/calendar.pdf"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    document.open();

    PdfPTable datatable = createHeaderTable();
    document.add(datatable);
    datatable = createFooterTable();

    drawTableAtTheEndOfPage(document, writer, datatable);

    document.close();
    System.out.println("done");
}

private static void drawTableAtTheEndOfPage(Document document, PdfWriter writer,
PdfPTable datatable) {
    datatable.setTotalWidth(
    document.right(document.rightMargin()) - 
    document.left(document.leftMargin()));

    datatable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(document.leftMargin()),
    datatable.getTotalHeight() + document.bottom(document.bottomMargin()),
    writer.getDirectContent());
}
```

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of a combination of questions. You should add your footer table in a page event. See [How to create a table with 2 rows that can be used as a footer?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-table-2-rows-can-be-used-footer) and [How to add a table as a header?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-table-header) When you add a table as a footer (or header), you don't need to worry about splitting the main table so that it is distributed automatically. You only need to make sure the margins are defined correctly.

Comment: But my intention is not have it on every single page, but only on the very last one. I had a look at links you send me and i studied them very carefully. I dont want to reserve space for one footer table at the very end of the whole document on every single page.
Or is is really possible just change somehow and use it in my problem too? I am still studying it but i am not sure.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I have reopened your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
  private static void drawTableAtTheEndOfPageAndWholeDocument
  (Document document, PdfWriter writer, PdfPTable datatable) 
  {
     datatable.setTotalWidth(document.right() - document.left());

     if (writer.getVerticalPosition(false) - datatable.getTotalHeight()
         - document.bottom() < 0) { 

      // new page if there is too little space for the final table on 
      // current page
        document.newPage();
     }

     datatable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, document.left(),
     datatable.getTotalHeight() + document.bottom(), 
     writer.getDirectContent());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I closed your question as a duplicate of [Why is my content overlapping with my footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33242501/why-is-my-content-overlapping-with-my-footer) because I (wrongly) assumed that you wanted to add a table to each page of the document.

You updated your question with a clarification, and it is now a duplicate of this question: [How to find out the current cursor position on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33428138/how-to-find-out-the-current-cursor-position-on-a-page)

Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to close a question as duplicate twice, hence I have to copy/paste my previous answer here:

> There is a very old method called `getVerticalPosition()` that takes a
>   `boolean` as parameter. I'm not proud of that method as it is a
>   *getter* method that not only will give you the Y position on the page after using a series of `document.add()` operations, it can also
>   change the current Y position (and that is not what a *getter* method
>   should do).
>
> If you pass `false` as a parameter, it will give you the current Y,
>   which could be the position of the baseline of the last `Chunk` you've
>   added.
>
> If you pass `true` as a parameter, the method will first add a newline
>   and give you the position of the baseline of the "next" line of text
>   you'll be adding.

Note that many design flaws (some of which that date back to my original design of iText dating from the year 2000) are fixed in iText 7; iText 7 is a complete rewrite of iText.

Comment: I had a look at that link. So if i understand it correctly, there is (in iText 5) no other choise than work with getVerticalPosition method.
Then this question is not duplicate because this is exactly what i asked about - whether there is another way how to handle this problem than manually work with this sort of method.
In my opinion is good to remain this question here, now it is clear that there is no other way.